# loopback number precision

Tags: numbers, precision, loopback

I'm using `postgresql` with `loopback`. I have a field in a model called `amount` being used as a `Number`. Now midway through the project, a new requirement came to hold `amount` value with precision. But I won't be able to store `amount` for example. as `1.50`, as it is converted and stored as `1.5`, which happens with javascript number type values.

Other approach for holding precision is to converting the property from `number` to `string`. But this change will be a major code change throughout all the modules.

Also there is a property called `precision` and `scale` for PostgreSQL connector. Is there any way in the model declaration (`.json` file) itself to hold precision with type `number`? Just wanted to be sure if there is any other approach before going through this change. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can these fields to the model.json. I have not tested the code but i think this will work

```
"amount": {
  "type": "Number",
  "required": true,
  "postgresql": {
      "dataType": "numeric",
      "dataPrecision": 20,
      "dataScale": 0
    }
}
```